# Table inside div

Tags: css, css-tables

I have layout with two left floating divs - one for a picture the other for content.  In the content div I have inserted a table to show some numeric data. When I add the table to the content div my float seems to get lost, the second div does not show up next to the first one but rather below.

Code example:

```
<div style="float:left;">
        <img src="images/image.jpg" width="200" height="125" alt="Image" /></p>
</div>

<div style="float:left; padding-left:16px;">
         <p>Paragraph text </p>

         <table width="650">
              ....
          </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, just taking a quick look, you have an orphaned `</p>` tag in your first div.

Comment: Thanks - I fixed the orphaned paragraph tag but that had no effect on the div floating problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the width of the parent div that contains these two divs, my guess is that the parent does not have enough width to accommodate both given their content and width settings.

```
<div  style="width:866px;overflow:hidden">
<div style="float:left;">
        <img src="images/image.jpg" width="200px" height="125" alt="Image" /></p>
</div>

<div style="float:left; padding-left:16px;">
         <p>Paragraph text </p>

         <table width="650px">
              ....
          </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The parent div has a 100% width.

Comment: 100% only means upto the parent's parent's width, it could be less than 200+650px of the two divs above. Please set the immediate parents width to be large enough to hold both divs side-by-side i.e. > 850px.

Comment: But I didn't really want a set width, I wanted to try to keep it flexible.

Comment: but you have set widths on the divs above :),  so you need a container large  enough to hold 'em

Comment: Sorry I'm new to a lot of this.  Even if the containers above have 100% width?

Comment: lets say you have parent-div and a child-div, all that width:100%, does set its element to occupy the full width of the parent. now you will have to go up the DOM tree to see if its 100% all the way up , which means the screen width, else  there is some element up the tree with width fixed to a px size which is not enough.   So, test the above code by setting a width >650

Comment: Ok, so I added a width of 866 to the parent div (200 for the image, 650 for the table and 16 for the left padding) but it still isn't working.  It shows okay in Dreamweaver but not in Chrome, Firefox or IE.

Comment: I also double checked an each of the parent elements have a width of 100%.

Comment: created a jsfiddle demo , looks fine in Chrome , IE8  -  http://jsfiddle.net/ds025csr/

Comment: Hmmm, I'm still not sure what is happening, but if I change my div widths to percentages it seems to work.  Thanks for all your help!